# How to iterate json data in txt file using node js?

Tags: node.js, file, nodejs-server

I tried to Iterate json data in txt file using file(fs) module.its json data is string format but I want object format.how to achieve it.

**amd.txt**

```
{
 "first_name":"iball"
}
{
 "first_name":"ibell"
}
```

**product.js**

```
fs.readFile("amd.txt","utf8", (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            let student = JSON.stringify(data);
            student = JSON.parse(student
            console.log(typeof student)
        });
```

**Current output**

```
string
```

**excepted output**

```
object
```

Comment: You stringified a string, *why* did you expect that to parse to an object?

Comment: First, you shouldn't re-encode to JSON before parsing it (remove `let student = JSON.stringify(data);`, using `parse` only should be enough). Second, there's a formatting problem, you shouldn't have 2 objects in your JSON, but rather an array of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try this, change the file amd.txt like so:

```
[
    {
        "first_name":"iball"
    },
    {
        "first_name":"ibell"
    }
]
```

then change your code like so:

```
fs.readFile("amd.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    students = JSON.parse(data);

    // Iterate list..
    console.log("Student list: ")
    students.forEach(student => {
        console.log(`First name: ${student.first_name}`);
    });
});
```

and I think you'll be much closer to the result you'd like!